# return; return true and return false - what are the differences?

Tags: php, javascript

In languages like javascript/c++, sometimes there are `return false;` or `return 0;` being used. However, in languages like PHP, `return;` stops the script, and `return false;` returns the (bool) false and continues the script.

It is confusing me alot lately.

Can anyone explain what are the usages of return?

Ps. My questions is mostly PHP/javascript/jQuery related.

Comment: The point of `return` is to return a value (or the lack thereof) from the current scope. Once a value is returned from said scope, anything after the return will not be executed. What happens as a result of the return depends on context.

Comment: There's also a manual: http://php.net/return

Comment: *"`return;` stops the script, and `return false;` returns the (bool) false and continues the script"* that sounds a bit strange. `return` **always** terminates the current function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return` sentence returns (duh) a value, the difference lays in what do you do with that value. For example, if you `return false` inside an `onclick`, the event isn't going to perform, if you `return true`, then it will.

`return` without an specified value, it will return `undefined`

Javascript example:

```
function myFunction(){ return "asd"; }
myvar = myFunction();
```

And then you use your `myvar` as any variable, so if you do

```
console.log(myvar);
```

that will log

```
"asd"
```

Answer (score 2):

In PHP,

```
return;
```

is equivalent to:

```
return null;
```

In Javascript, it's equivalent to:

```
return undefined;
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

> If no parameter is supplied, then the parentheses must be omitted and NULL will be returned.

If an argument is passed, then obviously that argument will be returned.